# Why is $routeParams not working? Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm triyng to build simple applications on Angular and Django rest framework.
I have a next root app:
**app.js**

```
angular
    .module('sharePhotoApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'sharePhotoApp.controllers',
    'sharePhotoApp.services'
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: '/',
          controller: 'PostListController'
        })
        .when('/:username', {
          templateUrl: '/user/',
          controller: 'UserDetailController'
         })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

And the next controller:

```
angular
    .module('sharePhotoApp.controllers')
    .controller('UserDetailController',  UserDetailController)

    UserDetailController.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams','userService'];

function UserDetailController($scope, $routeParams, userService){

    alert($routeParams.username);

    $scope.user = userService.get({ username: $routeParams.username });
}
```

I tried to follow the next URL in browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/#/admin
I suppose in this case should triggered route with username parameter.
But I've gotten undefined.
Could anyone explain where I done mistake?

Comment: isn't http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/user/admin instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/#/admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change
>   completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on
>   $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can
>   use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters."

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Have you also installed ngRoute module?

As the description says, the route is not finished in your controller, so the params are also undefined.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams should be populated here
  });
```

should do the work.

Comment: I got 'cannot read property 'params' of undefined. I have installed ngRoute in root app

Comment: 'cannot read property 'params' of undefined' !== routeParams undefined. You have somewhere a property which called params and the object is undefined. e.g. 'object.params...'

Comment: I just tried `alert($route.current.params.username);`

Comment: Or you do this (more elegant): $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams should be populated here
  });

Comment: `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { });` is working well!

Comment: Cheers m8. upvote and mark as solution. have a nice coding day ;)